# Shapefile or map of Mozambique localidades (localities) administrative boundaries

Tags: geospatial, africa

I am trying to find a shapefile for Mozambique's Level 4 administrative boundaries. These units are known as localidades, or localities, and there are over 1,000 of them. I've tried all the usual sources: GADM, etc. No source that I have found has anything below level 3 boundaries, which are districts.

Confusingly, some websites refer to level 3 districts as localities, but -- while this may have been correct years ago -- it is no longer right. There are ~450 districts and over 1000 localities in Mozambique.

At this point, I would be happy to find any map of localities, even piecemeal, that I could scan and assemble into a comprehensive shapefile. I am also open to alternative solutions, such as generating approximate polygons from a list of points known to reside within a given locality. But I have not found data that would allow me to do that yet.

Comment: "I've tried all the usual sources" - does that include openstreetmap.org and Mozambique's national website?

Comment: @BarryCarter Regarding openstreetmap: yes, I've tried there, though it's possible I missed something, as I don't use it often.  As for the Mozambican government websites, I've looked extensively but -- again -- I may have missed something, as my Portuguese is not great and Google Translate is only marginally helpful.

Comment: same question - any available shapefiles for admin4 (localidades) for Mozambique? erna

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://earthworks.stanford.edu/catalog/sde-columbia-iscgm_mozambique_2008_mispopp and https://data.humdata.org/dataset/mozambique-settlement-shapefiles